# How to filter a models field by multiple values (OR'd)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, input-filtering

I have a model say `Book` which has the following scope function:

```
scope :author, lambda { |author|
    return where(nil) unless author.present?
    joins(:author).where('author.id' => author)
  }
```

This can filter the Books with only ONE author value. What I want to do is that I am passed a array from a JavaScript file which is a list of authors for example: `["harry", "doyle", "alex", "parrish"]` and I want to be able to find all the books who has ANY of these authors (so an OR query here).  Note each book can have multiple authors.

I have tried the following function but it simply gives me all the books rather than filtering correctly as I stated above.

```
scope :authors_multiple, lambda { |authors|
  @results = Book
  authors.each do |auth|
    @results = @results.author(auth)
  end
  return @results
}
```

model Author (extract):

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :books, uniq: true
  ....
```

model Book (extract):

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :authors, uniq: true
  ....
```

Can you please help me understand what I am doing wrong or what may be the right way to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add your relations and schema? Book has the singular relation `author`. How are you storing multiple authors for a book?

Answer (score 0):

```
authors = ["harry", "doyle", "alex", "parrish"]  
Book.where(author: authors)
```

or

```
authors = ["harry", "doyle", "alex", "parrish"]  
auths = Author.where(name: authors)
Book.where(author: auths)
```

This assumes that an Author has many Books. 
You can learn more about model associations here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: books.author: SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."title" = ? AND "books"."year" = ? AND "books"."author" IN ('harry', 'doyle', 'owen', 'hall', 'shelby', 'whyte', 'alex', 'parrish') ORDER BY "books"."published_at" DESC`

Comment: Could you provide a copy of your structure.sql file? It sounds like you don't have a column named "author".

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get your `Author` records.  How this is done depends on your schema and data, but it will be something akin to:

```
author_names = ["harry", "doyle", "alex", "parrish"]
```

Then one of the following:

```
authors = Author.where(name: author_names)
authors = Author.where("name ILIKE ANY ( array[?] )", author_names.map { |name| "%#{name}%" })
```

Something that gets us an `ActiveRecord::Relation` of the authors we need.  Once we have the authors we can merge that with our books to get all the books we want:

```
books = Book.joins(:authors).merge(authors)
```

Note that the join is on the plural author**s**.  Rails will know to join through the join table (should be `authors_books` by default) to the `authors` table.

Comment: Hey i know we can use this `Author.find_by(name: auth).try(:id)` to convert the string  author into the actual author

Comment: `Author.where(name: author_names)` this would take the array much like the `find_by` uses a single name. Using `where` will prevent the records from loading though and leave them in an `ActiveRecord::Relation` which is needed for the merge operation. If the names listed are exactly those in the database you can use `Book.joins(:authors).merge(Author.where(name: author_names))`

Answer (score 0):

You get an array of author names, right?

```
scope :by_author, lambda { |names|
  # if you have a chance to get blank values you need to reject them
  names.reject!(&:blank?) if names.is_a? Array

  joins(:authors).where(authors: { name: names }).distinct if names.present?
}
```

It should work properly with array or string argument

```
Book.by_author(["harry", "doyle"])
Book.by_author("harry")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code:

```
authors = ["harry", "doyle", "alex", "parrish"]    
Book.joins(:authors).where(:authors => {:name => authors})
```